# Invalid results querying my system’s cache information with GetLogicalProcessorInformation()

Tags: c++, winapi, x86, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache

I wrote this small program to query and display information about my system's information on its cache.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
auto msg = [](std::string_view label, T value, std::string descriptor = std::string()) {
    std::cout << label.data() << ": " << value << descriptor << '\n' ;
};

const static std::array<std::string_view, 4> CacheTypes{
    "Unified",
    "Instruction",
    "Data",
    "Trace"
};

void QueryCacheInformation() {
    DWORD bufferSize = 0;
    GetLogicalProcessorInformation(0, &bufferSize);
    std::vector<SYSTEM_LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_INFORMATION> buffer(bufferSize / sizeof(SYSTEM_LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_INFORMATION));
    GetLogicalProcessorInformation(buffer.data(), &bufferSize);

    auto getCacheType = [](_PROCESSOR_CACHE_TYPE type) {
        return std::string(CacheTypes[type]); 
    };
   
    auto showAll = [&](int i, std::vector<SYSTEM_LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_INFORMATION> &buff) {
        msg<DWORD>(std::string_view("CPU L" + std::to_string(i) + " cache type"), static_cast<int>(buff[i].Cache.Type), std::string(" " + getCacheType(buff[i].Cache.Type)) );
        msg<DWORD>(std::string_view("CPU L" + std::to_string(i) + " cache size"), buff[i].Cache.Size, " bytes");
        msg<DWORD>(std::string_view("CPU L" + std::to_string(i) + " cache line size"), buff[i].Cache.LineSize, " bytes");
        std::cout << '\n';
    };

    for (auto& info : buffer) {
        switch (info.Cache.Level) {
        case 0:
            break;
        case 1:           
        case 2:
        case 3:
            showAll(info.Cache.Level, buffer);
            break;
        default:
            std::cout << "System has no cache!\n";
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    QueryCacheInformation();    
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

And this is the output when I run this program:

```
CPU L1 cache type: 2 Data
CPU L1 cache size: 32768 bytes
CPU L1 cache line size: 64 bytes

CPU L1 cache type: 2 Data
CPU L1 cache size: 32768 bytes
CPU L1 cache line size: 64 bytes

CPU L1 cache type: 2 Data
CPU L1 cache size: 32768 bytes
CPU L1 cache line size: 64 bytes

CPU L1 cache type: 2 Data
CPU L1 cache size: 32768 bytes
CPU L1 cache line size: 64 bytes

CPU L2 cache type: 1 Instruction
CPU L2 cache size: 32768 bytes
CPU L2 cache line size: 64 bytes

CPU L1 cache type: 2 Data
CPU L1 cache size: 32768 bytes
CPU L1 cache line size: 64 bytes

CPU L1 cache type: 2 Data
CPU L1 cache size: 32768 bytes
CPU L1 cache line size: 64 bytes

CPU L1 cache type: 2 Data
CPU L1 cache size: 32768 bytes
CPU L1 cache line size: 64 bytes

CPU L1 cache type: 2 Data
CPU L1 cache size: 32768 bytes
CPU L1 cache line size: 64 bytes

CPU L2 cache type: 1 Instruction
CPU L2 cache size: 32768 bytes
CPU L2 cache line size: 64 bytes

Press any key to continue . . .
```

The program appears to be querying through processor nodes and retrieving information about its caches and displaying the results. However, I'm running this program on my Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Quad CPU Q9650. I'm running this on a Windows 7 64b and I'm compiling this using MS Visual Studio 2017 with the language flag set to `ISO C++ Latest Draft Standard (/std:c++latest)`.

According to CPU-World's [datasheet](https://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/Core_2/Intel-Core%202%20Quad%20Q9650%20AT80569PJ080N%20(BX80569Q9650%20-%20BXC80569Q9650).html) pertaining to my specific processor, here is what it is reporting about my system's architecture and its cache:

| Cache Level | Cache Properties |
| --- | --- |
| Level 1 cache size | 4 x 32 KB 8-way set associative instruction caches |
|  | 4 x 32 KB 8-way set associative data caches |
| Level 2 cache size | 2 x 6 MB 24-way set associative caches (each L2 cache is shared between 2 cores) |

Lower on the page, it has these CPU ID tables with more information about its cache:

> TLB/Cache details:
>
> - 64-byte Prefetching
> - Data TLB: 4-KB Pages, 4-way set associative, 256 entries
> - Data TLB: 4-MB Pages, 4-way set associative, 32 entries
> - Instruction TLB: 2-MB pages, 4-way, 8 entries or 4M pages, 4-way, 4 entries
> - Instruction TLB: 4-KB Pages, 4-way set associative, 128 entries
> - L1 Data TLB: 4-KB pages, 4-way set associative, 16 entries
> - L1 Data TLB: 4-MB pages, 4-way set associative, 16 entries

---

| Cache: | L1 Data | L1 Instruction | L2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Size: | 4 x 32 KB | 4 x 32 KB | 2 x 6 MB |
| Associativity: | 8-way set associative | 8-way set associative | 24-way set associative |
| Line Size: | 64 bytes | 64 bytes | 64 bytes |
| Comments: | Direct-mapped | Direct-mapped | Non-inclusive Direct-Mapped 1 cache per 2 cores |

According to the datasheets, this should be the block diagram of my CPU's architecture.

[image: Q9650 Block Diagram]

However, this does not match the printed results from my program. According to the saved data structures from `GetLogicalProcessorInformation()` it is claiming that my CPU has 8 L1 Data Caches and 2 L2 Instruction Caches all having the same exact size which is not the case. Now as for the line sizes they are all the same and this information appears to be correct. It's just that the "types" and some of the "sizes" are not. My CPU should have a total of 128KB of L1 Data Cache, 128KB of L1 Instruction Cache, and 12MB of L2 Cache. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong and why I'm not getting matching values and types...

Am I querying and extracting the information correctly? Is it within the for loop, the switch statement, or the lambda's I'm using? Or something else that I'm completely overlooking?

I'm new to this API so any and all help, tips, and suggestions will be useful.

Comment: Aren't you supposed to check that `info.Relationship == RelationCache` before using the `Cache` field?

Comment: The data sheets you found are correct for quad-core Core2 systems like that.  A pair of cores (with private L1i/d) sharing an L2 cache.  Communication between cores that *don't* share an L2 is unfortunately about as slow as going through DRAM, although IIRC there is actually an interconnect that avoids actual store and reload (https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/cpumemory.pdf).  (Later CPUs, starting with Nehalem and especially Sandybridge, have more scalable designs.  https://www.realworldtech.com/nehalem/2/ compares Nehalem to Harpertown, the same core / cache arrangement as Yorkfield.)

Comment: (Intel's Quad-core Core2 CPUs were basically just sticking 2 dual-core dies in the same package; that's one reason they only communicate via the FSB (Frontside Bus).)

Comment: `info.Cache.Level` can only be 1, 2, or 3 according to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-cache_descriptor). You should remove `case 0` and change the printed string in the default case to "Something is really wrong and it's not my fault!".

Comment: @HadiBrais Maybe, but I'm not really sure as I'm fairly new to this part of the winapi... I only read enough to know what function to use and what parameters it takes to call it in order to query for the processors' information.

Comment: That wasn't an actual question. You definitely have to do that check and fix your switch cases. Also some processors have more cache levels, which will not be reported by `GetLogicalProcessorInformation`. These are all bugs in your code.

Comment: Hadi Brais, I completely understand. I wasn't doing this for "production" code. It was merely out of curiosity to familiarize myself with the API. I had taken several code samples and constructed my own version. From the samples I've seen, they were using macros and had a lot of code duplication. I decided to minimize the code duplication and replace the macros with lambdas. I'm only running this on my machine that is running Windows and I know my architecture and its properties. This was just for personal experimentation. I knew there was a bug but was having a hard time tracking it down.

Comment: I strongly recommend checking for errors as described in the documentation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in your lambda and the data you pass to it. You're using `i` (the cache level) to access elements of `buff` when you should be passing in the `info` value from your loop instead.

Change the lambda and call site to be like this:

```cpp
    auto showAll = [&](int i, SYSTEM_LOGICAL_PROCESSOR_INFORMATION &info) {
        msg<DWORD>(std::string_view("CPU L" + std::to_string(i) + " cache type"), static_cast<int>(info.Cache.Type), std::string(" " + getCacheType(info.Cache.Type)) );
        msg<DWORD>(std::string_view("CPU L" + std::to_string(i) + " cache size"), info.Cache.Size, " bytes");
        msg<DWORD>(std::string_view("CPU L" + std::to_string(i) + " cache line size"), info.Cache.LineSize, " bytes");
        std::cout << '\n';
    };
// ...
    showAll(info.Cache.Level, info);
```

(replacing `buff[i]` with `info` in the lambda, and passing in `info` instead of the `buffer` vector).

Comment: After reading this and then applying it, it's now making clear sense... At first, I couldn't easily see the bug because it was compiling and running without any errors and warnings. I even stepped through my debugger several times and still couldn't figure it out. It's times like these that you need a second set of eyes, another perspective!!! Thank You for the solution to my bug!!!